# Не работают, а служат, или История слова "работать"

Tags: этимология, выбор-слов, история

В одной телепрограмме, рассказывающей о жизни дворянства в России XIX века, было сказано (текст не дословный):

> Раньше не работали, а служили, так как слово *работать* происходит от слова *раб*.

Верны ли эти утверждения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Работать, служить, трудиться — что лучше?**

**Конечно, служить, ведь служить случается  по-разному:** можно быть слугой при барине, а можно служить Отечеству. В любом случае, слуга — это помощник, и.-е. основа slougo — помощь, служение.

**А как насчет работы?** Оказывается, только с 17 века слово  "работа" получило **постоянное значение** (и написание через букву А), когда работу стали связывать с трудовой деятельностью (а раньше это слово имело три значения: (1) рабство, неволя: (2) служение; (3) труд. После этого появились **производные слова:** работник, работный, прилагательное "рабочий" (в словарях с 1771 года) и, наконец, существительное "рабочий" — только в середине 19 века. Но вот заняты работники и рабочие **были только физическим трудом.**

**Итак, работать — это трудиться.** С одной стороны, труд создал человека, но вот происхождение у этого слова не из лучших. И.-е. основа troud —  **тереть**, мять, жать, давить, щемить, то есть всячески теснить и досаждать, в общем, труд — это забота, беспокойство, тяжелая ноша.

Так и сосуществовали с 11 века в русском языке эти два значения для слова "труд" — с одной стороны, работа, а с другой — скорбь, страдание, беспокойство.  **Но несмотря на этимологию, труд не связывают только с тяжелой физической работой.** В современном понятии труд — это   деятельность человека, направленная на создание  **материальных и духовных** ценностей. Но и первоначальное значение "трудный, тяжелый" также сохранилось   (трудная жизнь, трудная задача).

Answer (score 3):

Отвечаю конкретно на вопрос, рассуждать тут можно до бесконечности - все всегда будут по своему правы.

> Верны ли эти утверждения?

Очень мало в них верного.
Служили - царю. Как и сейчас, государственные служащие. Еще служили искусству - Мельпомене особенно (эта традиция частично сохранилась в театрах и по сей день, но отмирает). Науке. 
Военная была служба, естественная.

Ну если упрощать немного, то почти везде, где получали "жалование" (в основном это был интеллектуальный, как бы сейчас сказали, труд), а не договорную "плату [за работу]" люди служили. Чисто физический труд никто "службой" не назвал. 
Это разделение шло с незапамятных времен. Князю - служили. Термин "работа" означало нечто более узкое, сиюминутное. Как классная или домашняя работа в современной школе. Но при этом служба могла включать такую конкретную работу - и не одну. Современный термин во всех его оттенках сложился уже после революции. Об этом говорит и то, что в большинстве славянских слово это отсутствует или имеет другое, отличное от русского, значение.

Что касается слова "раб", то оно однокоренное с "работа", но никак не в том смысле, что одно *произошло* от другого. Дело в том, что "раб" означало не невольника (невольников так и называли невольниками), но скорее особого рода слугу. Не юридический социальный статус, а скорее - род занятий или условия "договора" или отношений к хозяину. Личная зависимость была не главное, хотя, конечно, играла заметную роль. Отсюда и "раб божий" - на современный язык это ближе всего "подданный", или с другой позиции - слуга. А слуга - это как раз от общего морфа с "служить", "служба".

Вот так все перемешалось...
То, что сказали по ящику, - примитивно и вульгарно (чтобы не сказать "неверно").

ЗЫ
Шанский - это школьный словарь, слишком упрощенно. 
Семёнов - тоже не авторитет, но он ближе к сути.

Answer (score 1):

Хрен редьки не слаще, или Служить (работать слугой) и работать (служить рабом) монопенисуальны по смысловой нагрузке.

Когда-то были синонимами в значении работать по найму, сейчас разошлись. У нас служащие работают. Как папа Карло.

Оба слова многозначны, см.:

[работать](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C),

[служить](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x).

Этимология слова "работать" разногласий у ведов не вызывает; возьмём, что под рукой, - Семёнова:

[**РАБОТАТЬ**](http://evartist.narod.ru/text15/020.htm)

> *Древнерусское – робота (рабство, неволя).*
>
> *Старославянское – работа (неволя).*
>
> В старославянский язык слово пришло из индоевропейского языка, в
>   котором корень **orbhos** имел значение «барщина, работа на кого-то».
>
> Первоначальное значение слова «работать» («трудиться на кого-то») по
>   мере его распространения приобрело ряд дополнительных оттенков:
>   «находиться в действии» (машина работает), «осуществлять какую-либо
>   деятельность» (работать над дипломом), «иметь постоянное место работы»
>   (работать пожарным) и т.п.

Шанский тоже неплох:

[**Рабо́та**](http://educador.narod.ru/index/istorija_slova_rabota/0-164)

> Общеславянское. Восходит к древнерусскому *робота*, развившемуся из
>   общеслав. *orbota, образованного с помощью суф. *-оtа* (> -ота), от
>   той же основы, что и *рабъ* (см.). Произношение и написание *работа*
>   вместо *робота* возникло в результате развития аканья и закрепления
>   его на письме (ср. диал. *робота*).

[**Раб**](http://educador.narod.ru/index/rab_ehtimologija_slova/0-163)

> Заимствовано из старославянского языка (ср. древнерусское *роба* —
>   «рабыня»). Старославянское *рабъ* восходит к общеславянскому *оrbъ,
>   имеющему индоевропейский характер (ср. латинское orbus — «лишенный
>   чего-нибудь», армянское orb — «сирота», древнеирландское orbe —
>   «наследник», древнеиндийское árbhas — «слабый» и др.). Сочетание *or*
>   в начале слова изменилось в старославянском языке в *ра* (у восточных
>   же славян — в *ро*).
>
> Первоначальное значение — «сирота», далее — «подневольный работник».